# Electric Current as a Derivative in time of Charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, charge

The definition of electric current is
$$I=\iint_S\vec{J}\cdot d\vec{a}$$where $\vec J$ is the current density, defined as
$$\vec J=\sum_in_iq_i\vec v_i$$and $S$ is the area which the charge passes through.

$n_i$ is the density of the $i$th type of charge, $q_i$ is the $i$th type of charge, and $\vec v_i$ is the velocity of that charge.

How can I derive from that definition the formula $I=\frac{dQ}{dt}$? and what does this $Q$ mean in the formula? It can't be the charge at the area $S$, because then it will be charge **density**, which doesn't get along with the units of $I$.

Comment: Gauss's law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law  It should be in your text someplace.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no derivation because it is a definition: $$Q=\int I \ dt$$ With that definition you can show $$Q=\int \left( \iint_S \sum_i n_i q_i \vec v_i \cdot d\vec a\right) \ dt$$ Now, for simplicity, let's assume that $n_i$ and $\vec v_i$ are constant both in space and time, so we have a uniform density of charges moving at a uniform velocity. And of course $q_i$ is also constant but that is not really an assumption. So we have $$Q=\int \left( \sum_i n_i q_i \vec v_i \cdot\iint_S  d\vec a\right) \ dt = \int \sum_i n_i q_i \vec v_i \cdot \vec A \ dt$$ Now, we will rewrite $\vec v_i = d\vec x_i/dt$ and change variables to get $$Q= \int \sum_i n_i q_i \vec A \cdot d\vec x = \sum_i n_i q_i \int \vec A \cdot d\vec x$$Now, at this point we have not assumed any particular relationship between $\vec A$ and $d\vec x$, but we can split $d\vec x$ into components $d\vec x_{\parallel}$ and $d\vec x_{\perp}$ which are respectively parallel and perpendicular to $\vec A$. So then  $$Q=  \sum_i n_i q_i \int \vec A \cdot d\vec x_{\parallel}=\sum_i n_i q_i V$$ where $V$ is the volume of charges that pass through $A$ over time.

Finally, $n_i$ is the number of charges per unit volume so $n_i V = N_i$ is just the total number of the $i$th type of charges in $V$ and so $$Q=\sum_i N_i q_i = \sum_i Q_i$$ meaning that $Q$ is just the sum of all of the charges in $V$.

The only tricky part of this concept is what is $V$. For convenience we assumed a uniform $v_i$. If it is not uniform then the math becomes more complicated, but $V$ is the volume that you would get by labeling all of the charges that flow through $A$ over the integration period.

Comment: Great explanation. But If it is a definition as you say, then Q represents something else at any moment, because the volume V is linearly increasing as the moving charge covers more volume. So I can't use Q to represent the charge of a constant volume like a capacitor, but in my book they do it (and that gives the oscillator equation for circuit and AC).

Comment: @Ben that is why I would consider $Q=\int I \ dt$ to be a definition. The $V$ is not essential to the definition. But in the context of a spatially and temporally uniform $v$ it makes sense. In other words, the volume $V$ is useful for motivating the definition, but it is not actually part of the definition.

Comment: @Dale you can also perform the derivation by taking $Q$ to be defined as $Q\equiv \int d^3r \rho(\vec r, t) = \int d^3r \sum_i q_i n_i$.

Comment: Yes. Either definition will indeed work. I prefer the one I posted because I like circuit theory, and it is the version appropriate for circuit theory.

Comment: @Dale as I mentioned, this formula is used for derivation of formulas for circuits, but as V is changing, it would be false for the charge of a capacitor for example, and thus the ODE for a standrad circuit cannot be derived (to get the formula you use $\mathcal{E}=Q/C$ and $Q=dI/dt$, but as you defined $Q$, it's not the same $Q$ as in the formula $\mathcal{E}=Q/C$.

Answer (score 0):

*Current* is defined as rate of flow of charge (that is charge flowing through a given area per unit time). We can correctly write $I=\int_S\mathbf J.d\mathbf S$. But, in my opinion, it would be an abuse of notation to write the definition of current as $I=\frac{dQ}{dt}$ or to put $\frac{dQ}{dt}=\int_S\mathbf J.d\mathbf S$. It is an abuse except when there is some definite amount, $Q$, of charge, of which $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ is the rate of change.

An exception, then, would be when considering the rate of charging of a capacitor with charges ±Q on its plates at some time $t$. $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ would then be both the current and the rate of *change* of $Q$.

Whether the abuse of notation, if such it be, causes any confusion is doubtful. [On the other hand, similar possible abuses in thermodynamics can cause the student serious trouble.]

Answer (score 0):

> In my electromagnetics book (*Electricity And Magnetism* by E.M.Purcell, chapter 4), the definition of electric current is
> $$I=\iint_S\vec{J}\cdot d\vec{a}$$where $\vec J$ is the current density, defined as
> $$\vec J=\sum_in_iq_i\vec v_i$$and $S$ is the area which the charge passes through.
> $n_i$ is the density of the $i$th type of charge, $q_i$ is the $i$th type of charge, and $\vec v_i$ is the velocity of that charge.

> How can I derive from that definition the formula $I=\frac{dQ}{dt}$ (there's no explanation in the book)?

This is a straight-forward application of continuity and the divergence theorem.

$$
I \equiv I_{in} - I_{out} =  -\int \vec {da}\cdot \sum_i q_i \vec v_i n_i(
\vec r,t) 
$$
$$
=-\int d^3r \frac{\partial }{\partial \vec r}\cdot \sum_i q_i \vec v_i n_i(\vec r,t)
$$
$$
=-\int d^3r  \sum_i q_i \vec v_i \cdot\frac{\partial }{\partial \vec r}n_i(\vec r,t)
$$
$$
=+\int d^3r  \sum_i q_i \vec v_i \cdot\frac{\partial }{\partial \vec x_i}n_i(\vec r,t)\tag{A}
$$
$$
=\int d^3r  \sum_i q_i \frac{d\vec x_i}{dt} \cdot\frac{\partial }{\partial \vec x_i}n_i(\vec r,t)
$$
$$
=\int d^3r  \sum_i q_i \frac{\partial}{\partial t}n_i(\vec r,t)
$$
$$
=\frac{d}{d t}\int d^3r  \sum_i q_i n_i(\vec r,t)
$$
$$
=\frac{dQ}{d t}\;,
$$
where Eq. (A) follows by assuming the time-dependence of $n_i(\vec r, t)$ depends on the difference $\vec r - \vec x_i(t)$, which is the case, for example, for a swarm of point particles.

---

To understand the above more fully, it could be helpful to start from the "other direction," e.g., start from:
$$
\rho(\vec r, t) = \sum_i q_i n_i = \sum_i q_i \delta(\vec r - \vec x_i(t))\;,
$$
where the latter expression for $n_i$ is appropriate for a swarm of point particles.

Take the partial derivative w.r.t time:
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \sum_i q_i \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\delta(\vec r - \vec x_i(t)) 
$$
$$
= -\sum_i q_i \frac{d \vec x_i}{d t}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec r}\delta(\vec r - \vec x_i(t)) 
$$
$$
=-\nabla \cdot \vec J\;,\tag{1}
$$
which is just the usual continuity equation.

But, on to what you are interested in... Integrate Eq. (1). over the volume of interest to see that:
$$
\frac{dQ}{dt} = -\int d^3r
\sum_i q_i \frac{d \vec x_i}{d t}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec r}\delta(\vec r - \vec x_i(t)) 
$$
$$
= -\int d^3r \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec r}\cdot
\sum_i q_i \frac{d \vec x_i}{d t} \delta(\vec r - \vec x_i(t))
$$
$$
=-\int \vec {da}\cdot \sum_i q_i \frac{d \vec x_i}{d t} \delta(\vec r - \vec x_i(t))
$$
$$
=-\int \vec {da}\cdot \sum_i q_i \vec v_i n_i \tag{2}
$$
$$
=-\int \vec {da}\cdot \vec J = I_{in} - I_{out}\;,
$$
where the third equation follows from [the divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem), and the Equation tagged (2) follows from your defintions, and the last equation follows, for example, by considering a cylindrical wire where the $I_{in}$ flows into the wire through one face and the $I_{out}$ flows out of the wire through the other face. (The signs follow by taking the normal pointing outwards in all cases.)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm getting lost with your notation. What is derivative over a vector? And what is delta?

Comment: The derivative of a vector is another vector that specifies the change of the first vector. This is basic vector calculus. It is going to be very difficult to understand your textbook without this background knowledge of vector calculus. The delta symbol indicates a Dirac Delta function. It is very common in physics, and you can google "dirac delta" to find out more information.

Comment: @Ben Also if by "derivative over a vector" you mean my $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec r}$, this just means the same thing as the usual "nabla" operator $\vec \nabla$. It means $\hat x{\frac{\partial }{\partial x}}+\hat y{\frac{\partial }{\partial y}}+\hat z{\frac{\partial }{\partial z}}$.